# taking the sum of a TRUE/FALSE vector in r

Tags: r

I am working analyzing SNP data for a fungus, and I am trying to impute the missing data by changing the Ns to the genotype of the more frequent allele....see below. 
newdata is a matrix of my snps (rows)and fungal isolates(columns). The genotypes for each snp are in the 0, 1, and N format, and that is why I am trying to impute the missing genotypes.

```
newdata_imputed=newdata
for (k in 1:nrow(newdata)){
u=newdata[k,]
x<-sum(u==0)
y<-sum(u==1)
all_freq=y/(x+y)
if (all_freq<0.5){
newdata_imputed[k,]=gsub("N",0,u)
} else{newdata_imputed[k,]=gsub("N",1,u)}
print(k)
}
```

However, I keep getting this error:

```
[1] 295
[1] 296
Error in if (all_freq < 0.5) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

It is obvious that the code runs but stops after encountering a problem. Please, can someone tell me what I am doing wrong? I am a newbie to R, and any advice would be greatly appreciated.

@akrun, the reason why i used a for loop is because it is nested in another for loop..so after using your code.

```
newdata=as.data.frame(newdata)
u=newdata
all_freq <- rowSums(u==1)/rowSums((u==1)|(u==0))
indx <- all_freq < 0.5
indx1 <-  indx & !is.na(indx)
indx2 <- !indx & !is.na(indx)
newdata[indx1,] <- lapply(newdata[indx1,], gsub, pattern='N', replacement=0)
newdata[indx2,] <- lapply(newdata[indx2,], gsub, pattern='N', replacement=1)
newdata[] <- lapply(newdata, as.numeric)
```

I got weird values

```
newdata[1:10,1:10]
   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10
1   3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3   3
2   2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2   2
3   3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3   3
4   1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1   1
```

Please where is the "3" coming from.???? I should only have 0 or 1

Comment: Looks like you have a row which lacks `0` or `1` values.

Comment: I think if you pasted some data to make your code _reproducible_, that would go a long way here.

Comment: Looks like pasting row 297 might be most helpful.

Comment: You may not need a `for` loop.  You could use `all_freq <- rowMeans(newdata==1); i1 <- all_freq<0.5` and use that index to replace the row values.

Comment: I guess `x + y == 0`. Then `all_freq == NaN` and `(all_freq<0.5) == NA`. The `if` reports this error if used with `NA`.

Comment: @Matthew, your comment is appreciated. I tried using akrun's code and didn't get the error I got before. but I got another error :-(. see my edited question.

Comment: @Tim, abergant. your comments are appreciated. I tried using akrun's code and didn't get the error I got before. but I got another error :-(. see my edited question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could do this using `rowSums`.  As @bergant and @MatthewLundberg mentioned in the comments, if there are rows with no 0 or 1 elements, we get `NaN` based on the calculation.  One way would be to modify the logical condition by including `!is.na`, i.e. elements that are not `NA` along with the previous condition.

```
#using `rowSums` to create the all_freq vector 
all_freq <- rowSums(newdata==1)/rowSums((newdata==1)|(newdata==0))
#Create a logical index based on elements that are less than 0.5
indx <- all_freq < 0.5 
#The NA elements can be changed to FALSE by adding another condition
indx1 <-  indx & !is.na(indx)
#similarly for elements that are > 0.5 
indx2 <- !indx & !is.na(indx)
```

Now, we subset the rows of the 'newdata' with 'indx1', loop through the columns (`lapply`) and use `gsub` with `pattern` and `replacement` arguments and assign the output back to the subset of 'newdata'.

```
newdata[indx1,] <- lapply(newdata[indx1,], gsub, pattern='N', replacement=0)
```

Similarly, we can do the replacement for the rows that are greater than 0.5 for 'all_freq'

```
newdata[indx2,] <- lapply(newdata[indx2,], gsub, pattern='N', replacement=1)
```

The `gsub` output columns are `character` class, which can be converted back to `numeric` (if needed).

```
newdata[] <- lapply(newdata, as.numeric)
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
newdata <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(c(0:1, "N"), 10*4, replace=TRUE),
         ncol=4), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
newdata[7,] <- 2
```

Comment: okay, your code worked with no error. but I got weird numbers....i should get 0s and 1s, but I am getting 2s and 3s. Did I do something wrong while tweaking the code?

Comment: @Nolage86  Please update your post with a small example data and expected output based on that.  I would use `dput` to show the example.  i.e. `dput(droplevels(newdata[1:5, 1:5])))`

Comment: @akrun.....after much effort, I finally figured out the source of the error. Your code was very helpful. Thanks a LOT! :-)

Comment: @akrun..........thanks for reminding me to click the tick mark. I'm definitely a newbie here :-). First, I had to recode my data entirely. Then, I had to remove the monomorphic markers (rows). the code would not work if I had markers in which the genotype was the same for all taxa (columns). Again, thank you. Coding gurus like you are a real blessing for newbies like me. :-)